# Trying to split a string into words containing only letters and/or apostrophes

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to split the string below into words that include only letters and/or apostrophes('). However, it is returning an empty string as the first element in the array. Why is my Regex returning that empty string?

```
pry(main)> "  //wont won't won't".split(/[^a-z']+/i)
=> ["", "wont", "won't", "won't"]
```

Why is my Regex returning that empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to `split` (or place a break in your string if you will) at anything that does NOT match your pattern right?  The very first thing in the string results in a split (or break) which in turn results in the first element being empty.

There are various ways of dealing with empty array elements like that, but I would suggest you consider using `scan` instead of `split`.  Using this approach you're actually doing the more logical thing.  You're looking for matches and sending those to your array (instead of looking for non-matches and splitting the original string up):

```
"  //wont won't won't".scan(/[a-z']+/i)  #=>  ["wont", "won't", "won't"]
```